# Transform string into correct date

Tags: c#, vb.net

What would be the best method to convert this string

```
Dim MyString As String = "20150728-02:21:44.952"
```

into this

```
"2015/07/28 02:21:44.952"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# equivalent:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("20150728-02:21:44.952", 
                               "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.fff", 
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var dateAsString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

And this is what Telerik converter gave me:

```
Dim [date] = DateTime.ParseExact("20150728-02:21:44.952", 
                                 "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Dim dateAsString = [date].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```